# Add checkbox to auto complete -jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on this code and I have used jQuery UI for autocomplete. Now I need some help in adding check-boxes to it so that i can do multiple selections and it reflect on my field with comma separation. I found a plugin exactly what I want to create but I don't want to use any plugin for [my work] http://www.igniteui.com/combo/selection-and-checkboxes

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
<body>
    <input id="condition" type="text" placeholder="condition">
</body>
<script>
    var availableTags = [
               "ActionScript",
               "AppleScript",
               "Asp",
               "BASIC",
               "C",
               "C++",
               "Clojure",
               "COBOL",
               "ColdFusion",
               "Erlang",
               "Fortran",
               "Groovy",
               "Haskell",
               "Java",
               "JavaScript",
               "Lisp",
               "Perl",
               "PHP",
               "Python",
               "Ruby",
               "Scala",
               "Scheme"
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#condition').autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength: 0
        }).focus(function () {
            try {
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
            }
            catch (e) {

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ***I don't want to use any plugin for my work***, then why use jquery?

Comment: Any plugins created by third party will create dependencies and it ll contradict with jquery ui too. I dont want it to make any future work or expansions to be affected by any plugins

Comment: you are posting duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913983/adding-checkbox-for-multiple-selection-in-autocomplete

Comment: cuz i m in some kind of urgency and that was not even replied.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you first need to alter the jQuery autocomplete's output.

Something like this

```
$('yourElement').autocomplete({ /* autocomplete config here */ }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    var checked = ($.inArray(item.label, selectedItems) >= 0 ? 'checked' : '');

    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( '<a><input type="checkbox" ' + checked + '/>' + item.label + '</a>' )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Then you have to store the picked elements in a variable (an array)

```
$('#yourElement').autocomplete({
    // Configs
    select:function(event, ui) {// Onselect event
        // Don't forget to check if the item is already in the array
        // and if it's the case to remove it

        selectedItems.push(ui.item.label); 
    }
});
```

Take not that *selectItems* is an array, you'll need define in your script

You can see on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meyunusx/1/) what this code gonna output in the autocomplete's list

Hope it will help you a bit