# Select mutiple options from jquery autocomplete with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working with [jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) .

I am trying following code

**Html**

```
<textarea class="search-element"></textarea>
```

**Script**

```
var data = [
               "ActionScript",
               "AppleScript",
               "Asp",
               "BASIC",
               "C++",
               "Clojure",
               "COBOL",
               "ColdFusion"
        ];
        $(function () {
            var $this;
            var singleSelectOptions = {
                source: function (request, response) {
                   response($.map(data, function (item) {
                      return {
                        label: item,
                      }
                   }));
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                   $($this).autocomplete("close");
                   $($this).val($($this).val() + '\n' + ui.label)
                 },
                 minLength: 0,
                 open: function () {
                    $("ul.ui-menu").width($(this).innerWidth());
                 }
            }
            $(document).find('textarea[class*="search-element"]').live('keydown', function () {
                $($this).autocomplete(singleSelectOptions);
            }).live('focus', function () {
                $this = $(this);
                var text = $this.val();
                if (text == '') {
                    $($this).autocomplete(singleSelectOptions);
                    $($this).autocomplete("search");
                }
          });
        })
```

By using this code I can select only one option at a time
but i need to select multiple options using checkbox

Right now my result is showing like this

[image]

But I want result as follows and when we check box then autocomplete should not be close and selected options should be fill in related textarea with comma separation and when we uncheck checkbox then that option should be remove from textarea.  And I can update text of textarea.

[image]

[**Here is my fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/32Bck/354/)

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930459/add-checkbox-to-auto-complete-jquery

Comment: Yes I have tried that also but can't reach to my goal I need more suggestions @RicardoPontual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried following code and my goal is achieved with this.

**Html**

```
 <textarea class="multiselect-element"></textarea>
```

**Script**

```
 var data = [
                   "ActionScript",
                   "AppleScript",
                   "Asp",
                   "BASIC",
                   "C++",
                   "Clojure",
                   "COBOL",
                   "ColdFusion"
            ];
            function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
}
function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}
function bindAutoComplete(ele, options) {
    var text = ele.val();
    text = text == null || text == undefined ? "" : text;
    $(ele).autocomplete(options).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        var checked = (text.indexOf(item.label + ', ') > -1 ? 'checked' : '');
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append('<a href="javascript:;"><input type="checkbox"' + checked + '/>' + item.label + '</a>')
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
}
$(function () {
    var $this;
    var multiSelectOptions = {
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item
                }
            }));
        },
        focus: function () {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            //$($this).autocomplete("search");
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var text = $this.val();
            text = text == null || text == undefined ? "" : text;
            var checked = (text.indexOf(ui.item.value + ', ') > -1 ? 'checked' : '');
            if (checked == 'checked') {
                this.value = this.value.replace(ui.item.value + ', ', '')
            }
            else {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");
            }
            return false;
        },
        open: function () {
           $("ul.ui-menu").width($(this).innerWidth());
        }
    }
    $(document).find('textarea[class*="multiselect-element"]').live('keydown', function () {
        bindAutoComplete($this, multiSelectOptions);
    }).live('focus', function () {
        $this = $(this);
        var text = $this.val();
        bindAutoComplete($this, multiSelectOptions);
        $($this).autocomplete("search");
    })
})
```

[**Here is my working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoj/32Bck/357/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Multi-Select-Autocomplete-Dropdown-Plugin-For-jQuery-MSelectDialogBox/

see --> reffer to second demo

Comment: not option but you can select multiple option select at a one time

Comment: I need checkboxes with options

Comment: using this library and <option> tag instead of <li> tag.
currently in demo <li>  tag you can change the <option> tag 

Hope you got same result what you want.

Thanks