# Search using javascript focus on what the search word

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, search

sorry if it hard to understand. i have to create some code about focusing the word what we want to search. i give you example

1. let say that, when we enter the page. the checkbox is from DB table "drinks"

[image]

2. then when i insert word in search area. it will focusing and eleminate the checkbox

[image]

3. when i select some of them

[image]

and press the reset. it will display all the checkbox but the selected is not disappear..

[image]

is there example code for this?

Comment: So where is your code that currently does all of that? Post it in your question

Comment: have a look at listjs (http://listjs.com/), it does a lot of what you ask

Comment: Some `hide()` and `show()` don't do the job?

Comment: Is this an assignment ?

Comment: What happen if I select `ice chocolate` then search with the word `tea` ? Should `ice chocolate` still be here or not? And if you validate shoud it be considered as `:checked` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you are looking for.

Here is an example that looks at the text for each checkbox and will either hide or show them. Pressing reset just empties the search box and presses the search button again.

The event listeners are just a way to listen for button presses then `dispatchEvent` is just faking a button press.

If any of this is confusing feel free to ask.

```js
const popSearch = document.querySelector('.pop_search');
const popSearchInput = popSearch.querySelector('.input');
const popSearchSearch = popSearch.querySelector('.search');
const popSearchReset = popSearch.querySelector('.reset');
const filterList = document.querySelector('.filter_list');

popSearchSearch.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let item of filterList.querySelectorAll('li')) {
    if (item.textContent.includes(popSearchInput.value)) {
      item.removeAttribute('hidden')
    } else {
      item.setAttribute('hidden', '')
    }
  }
});

popSearchReset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popSearchInput.value = "";
  popSearchSearch.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
});
```

```css
ul.filter_list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="pop_search">
  <input class="input" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="search">Search</button>
  <button class="reset">Reset</button>
</p>

<ul class="filter_list">
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />ice tea</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />ice lemon tea</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />ice coffee</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />bubble tea</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />milk tea</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />hot chocolate</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="checkbox" />ice chocolate</label></li>
</ul>
```

I hope you find this helpful

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Solutions that I can think of for this:

1.) Use autocomplete with the inclusion of checkboxes in the autocomplete options. You'll have to modify and include the checkbox in the options. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930459/add-checkbox-to-auto-complete-jquery) can help you with that.

2.) Convert that to the tag system i.e., remove the checkboxes and when you select any option then display it as tag. That way you can add/remove the options easily. For this you can use [Select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage). Refer the multiple option in the link, you'll get what I am referring to.

Hope this helps.